# How can I test if a string on distinct numbers/characters is random?

Tags: randomness

Let's say I have a string of 26 letters. I want to permute them and then test if my permutation is random. How do I do this?

Comment: This would be a variant of Benford's Law ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford's_law   Are they natural language letters where, e.g., 'e' is the most frequently occurring letter in English? Examine the frequency distribution of the permutations. If there are no naturally occurring anomalies (like the frequency of the letter 'e') then, it should be uniform or close to it.

Comment: Please explain what it might mean for a permutation to be "random."  What probability distribution do you have in mind?